# How to collect strings, sent from angularJS, in NodeRED array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, node.js, node-red

I'm trying to collect strings I send from AngularJS to a NodeRED array. The AngularJS code looks like this

```
 this.user =
   {
     medName1: '',
     medTime1: ''
   },
   {
     medName2: '',
     medTime2: ''
   },
   {
    medName3: '',
    medTime3: ''
   };
```

I'm collecting form data in medName1, medTime1,.. and so on. I'm trying to send this data, over websocket, one by one to NodeRED using the following code

```
 this.register = function() {
 $scope.sock.send(this.user.medName1);
 $scope.sock.send(this.user.medTime1);
 $scope.sock.send(this.user.medName2);
 $scope.sock.send(this.user.medTime2);
 $scope.sock.send(this.user.medName3);
 $scope.sock.send(this.user.medTime3);
}
```

register() is called when I click on "submit" button.

My question is - **How do I store these strings in a nodeRED array?**. Because the way I'm sending it, the string always gets stored in array index 0, overwriting the previous string. I also tried

```
 $scope.sock.send(JSON.stringify(this.user));
```

but it sends the entire thing as a string to nodeRED which then makes it impossible to extract the values assigned to medName1, medTime1, and so on.

Can anyone please suggest a way!.. I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send the json.stingify version, you can then use a JSON node in your Node-RED flow to convert it back to the JavaScript object you want.

Answer (score 0):

First, make your `this.user` an actual array:

```
this.user =[
   {
     medName1: '',
     medTime1: ''
   },
   {
     medName2: '',
     medTime2: ''
   },
   {
    medName3: '',
    medTime3: ''
   }];
```

Then, send the `this.user` array in a single step just as you mentioned:

```
this.register = function() {
   $scope.sock.send(JSON.stringify(this.user));
}
```

Then, in NodeRED use this:

```
 var user_array = JSON.parse( the_serialized_array );
```

Comment: I'd tried the way you suggested, but in this case the entire array goes as a string to nodeRED.

Comment: and if you send it like $scope.sock.send(this.user); ?

Comment: It sends a string [object Object]

Comment: I edited my answer - is using JSON.parse() on NodeRED helping you ?

Comment: Using JSON.parse throws an error for me in NodeRED, saying JSON is not defined or something like that. It's OK. I've got it working thanks to @knolleary. And thank you Tudor for your help as well.

Comment: Ok, don't forget to upvote and accept his answer, as a sign of appreciation